# How to create a custom drag shadow?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to create a drag and drop functionality in Android. I'd like to use a specific layout (different from the dragged object itself) as a drag shadow.

**What result I'm getting instead:**

Neither of my approaches works as expected - I end up with no visible drag shadow at all (although the target does receive the drop).

**What I tried:**

I tried

- inflating the `drag_item` layout in the activity, then passing it as an argument to the shadow builder's constructor

and

- inflating the `drag_item` layout in the shadow builder's `onDrawShadow` method, then drawing it on the `canvas`

**Layouts:**

My activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context="com.example.app.DragDropTestActivity"
              tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReceiver"
        android:text="Drop here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDragged"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drag me"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout I want to use as a drag shadow:

`dragged_item.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dragged Item"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Source code:**

Here's the code with both approaches (represented by `1`, `BuilderOne` and `2`, `BuilderTwo`, respectively):

```
package com.example.app;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DragDropTestActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag_drop_test);
        Button dragged = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDragged);

        dragged.setOnTouchListener(
            new View.OnTouchListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                    int approach = 1;    
                    // both approaches fail
                    switch (approach) {
                        case 1: {
                            View draggedItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dragged_item, null);
                            BuilderOne builder = new BuilderOne(draggedItem);
                            v.startDrag(null, builder, null, 0);
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2: {
                            BuilderTwo builder = new BuilderTwo(inflater, v);
                            v.startDrag(null, builder, null, 0);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
```

My `BuilderOne` class:

```
    public static class BuilderOne extends View.DragShadowBuilder
    {
        public BuilderOne(View view)
        {
            super(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint)
        {
            super.onProvideShadowMetrics(
                shadowSize,
                shadowTouchPoint);
        }
    }
```

And `BuilderTwo` class:

```
    public static class BuilderTwo extends View.DragShadowBuilder
    {
        final LayoutInflater inflater;

        public BuilderTwo(LayoutInflater inflater, View view)
        {
            super(view);
            this.inflater = inflater;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint)
        {
            super.onProvideShadowMetrics(
                shadowSize,
                shadowTouchPoint);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)
        {
            final View draggedItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dragged_item, null);
            if (draggedItem != null) {
                draggedItem.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

What do I do wrong?

**Update:**

Bounty added.

Answer (score 2):

Kurty is correct in that you shouldn't need to subclass `DragShadowBuilder` in this case. My thought is that the view you're passing to the `DragShadowBuilder` doesn't actually exist in the layout, and therefore it doesn't render.

Rather than passing `null` as the second argument to `inflater.inflate`, try actually adding the inflated `View` to the hierarchy somewhere, and then passing it to a regular `DragShadowBuilder`:

```
View dragView = findViewById(R.id.dragged_item);
mDragShadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(dragView);
v.startDrag(null, mDragShadowBuilder, null, 0);
```

**EDIT**

I'm aware that having the `dragged_item` view being rendered all the time isn't what you want, but if it works then at least we know where the problem is and can look for a solution to that instead!

Comment: That's some idea. Maybe I could add it somewhere where it's not visible to the user (but still part of the layout)? It would still be a hack, but if it does the trick... I'll try that when I get home

Comment: Another idea (and the way I'm currently doing my custom DropShadow) is to only use the `View` to set the dimensions of the `Canvas` used in `onDrawShadow`, and then reconstruct the appearance manually in an overridden `onDrawShadow`. You might be able to access the text stored in the inflated `View` with `CharSequence text = ((TextView) getView()).getText()` and then use the result of that in [Canvas.drawText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

Comment: Did this end up helping you out, @KonradMorawski?

Comment: Sorry. Well I didn't have time to dig deeper and I ended up with a compromise, taking out a *part* of the dragged object and using this as my shadow. Good enough, but not really a custom view. You're probably correct that the root problem is the shadow only exists in the abstract and thus never gets "actually" inflated = has no dimensions. I didn't try the trick with a tucked away view. I +1 your answer as it points in the right direction, but I can't accept it, because it doesn't answer the problem fully, it's bit of a hack. I still believe there's some proper way to do it. Thanks anyhow

Comment: It seems like you could render the view as a bitmap, then use the bitmap to instantiate the DragShadowBuilder.  Render a view as a bitmap looks something like:

Comment: To finish this thought, here is a link to do that rendering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346710/bitmap-from-view-not-displayed-on-android

Comment: For the record, I tried this approach and got it working. I have a view (drag_shadow_base) sitting behind the view the user actually sees. drag_shadow_base is what I then pass in to the drag builder. There's overdraw here, but hey, it works.

Answer (score -2):

Simply put it, you only need this:

```
private final class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.startDrag(ClipData.newPlainText("", ""), new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), v, 0);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

(You don't necessarily need the BuilderOne and BuilderTwo class)

Comment: Your solution misses the point. It will get me the default shadow (`btnDragged` itself). And not `dragged_item`, which I wanted to use instead.